# how to using parameter in modified java pentaho

Tags: dynamic, filenames, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

my boss wants to send email every morning with filename+date(yyyymmdd)
i've used "get file names" in the folder.
the problem is, the filename in "get file name" is only direct for example 'sales comparation.xlsx' but what we want is filename+date(yyyymmdd) to be 'sales comparison (20220701).xlsx.
I have prepared a parameter/variable that reads date(yyyymmdd), and added a "Modified Java Script Value" design so that the file is dynamically changed to the desired one.

I couldn't find on the forum what I was hoping for. can anyone help please send a kettle or a photo for easy understanding.

best regards

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KUxx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8QNU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ictv2.png)

Comment: I think you need to explain better what you are trying to achieve. Why don't you generate the file with the name+date format? Or is the file not generated by PDI so you don't have control over the name of the file? Then I would better rename the file and then send the file in the email. The Move file action for jobs allows has a check box to add the date to the destination file name.

Answer (score 0):

I think some ways to solve ur problem, i guess.

1.- Using "Join rows (cartesian product)" in the transformation where u get file name.
[join rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heI7E.png), after thar concat values with Mod JS or concat fields.

2.- If u use "Set Variable" u should use "Get variable" like this:

[Set Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gylx.png)

[Get Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0dCw.png)

Also u should declare in Transformation properties

[Transf Prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZpNv.png)

3.- Using parameters i did with "Copy rows to result", u should declare parameters in "Transformation" job entry configuration "parameters" like this:

[Transformation configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEce1.png)

Variables and parameters are diferent things.

Edit about comment:

[sent values for parameters and variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHmop.png)

[Set variable config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD4yf.png)

Comment: But that won't help the OP to change the filename of the file he wants to attach to the mail, the mail step in the transformation uses the filename of the file you are attaching. If he needs to send the file with a different name, he needs to change the name of the file before executing the transformation to send the mail.

Comment: So, he should send the name with "Set Variables" in previous transformation, and the another transf.. get variable with the name, i'll edit the answer with another pic